# оставить только уникальные элементы в многомерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Как сделать так чтобы оставались только уникальные значения

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

function super_unique($array,$key){
    $temp_array = [];
    foreach ($array as &$v) {
        if (!isset($temp_array[$v[$key]]))
        $temp_array[$v[$key]] =& $v;
    }
    $array = array_values($temp_array);
    return $array;

}

$arr = array();
$arr[0]['id'] = null; 
$arr[0]['name'] = 'John';

$arr[1]['id'] = 12; 
$arr[1]['name'] = 'John';

$arr[2]['id'] = null; 
$arr[2]['name'] = null; 

$arr[3]['id'] = 54; 
$arr[3]['name'] = 'Ammie'; 

$arr[4]['id'] = 23; 
$arr[4]['name'] = 'Martin'; 

$arr[5]['id'] = 54; 
$arr[5]['name'] = null; 

$arr[6]['id'] = 342; 
$arr[6]['name'] = 'Anna'; 

$arr[7]['id'] = 64; 
$arr[7]['name'] = 'Tom'; 

$arr[8]['id'] = 64; 
$arr[8]['name'] = null; 

$arr[9]['id'] = 364; 
$arr[9]['name'] = null; 

$arr[10]['id'] = null; 
$arr[10]['name'] = 'Piter'; 


$arr = super_unique($arr,'id');
$arr = super_unique($arr,'name');

$arr = array_values($arr);

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Я хочу добиться такого результата

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": 54,
        "name": "Ammie"
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "Martin"
    },
    {
        "id": 342,
        "name": "Anna"
    },
    {
        "id": 64,
        "name": "Tom"
    },
    {
        "id": 364,
        "name": null
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": 'Piter'
    }
]
```

Comment: Что делать, если имя одинаковое, а id разный? Какой тогда элемент брать: с наибольшим id?

Comment: такой ситуаций не будет

Comment: У вас уже это в коде есть. Имя "John" в массиве есть дважды.

Comment: И да, если такой ситуации не может быть, то логика в вопросе отсутствует, поскольку Вы говорите, что нужно, чтобы остались только уникальные значения.

Comment: не будет такого чтобы например John 545 и John 748

там может быть только null или 1 уникальный id имена тоже уникальные 

и там даже не имя а идентификатор написал имя потому что так проще объяснить

Comment: Вы не указали критерий уникальности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В stackoverflow на английском мне дали следующий ответ:

```
//This function will get you the missing field from the array:
function getField($arr, $key, $value, $newKey) {
    foreach($arr as $e)
        if (($e[$key] == $value) && $e[$newKey])
            return $e[$newKey];
}

function uniqueArray($arr){
    $res = array();
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if (!$a["id"] && !$a["name"])
            continue; // if both null ignore
        if (!$a["id"]) // if id missing go get it
            $a["id"] = getField($arr, "name", $a["name"], "id");
        if (!$a["name"]) // fill the name if missing
            $a["name"] = getField($arr, "id", $a["id"], "name");
        $res[] = $a; // as to result array
    }

    $r = array_map("json_decode", array_unique(array_map("json_encode", $res)));

    return array_values($r);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через рекурсию

```
function super_unique($array,$temp=[],$key=0){
if ($key==(count($array)-1)) return $temp;
if(!array_search($array[$key]['name'],array_column($temp,'name')))$temp[]=[$array[$key]['id']=>$array[$key]['name']];
  $key++;
   return super_unique($array,$temp,$key);
else {
  $key++;
  return super_unique($array,$temp,$key);
}
$temp_arr=super_unique($array);
```

Comment: для чего нужны key и temp?

Comment: Для начала было бы неплохо галочку поставить, если работает...

Comment: key здесь порядковый ключ вашего arr, а temp временный массив, в который добавляются элементы

Comment: я в php новичок не смог использовать эту функцию и поэтому решил уточнить за что отвечает temp и key

echo count(super_unique($arrayWithDuplicates));

Comment: Они вам не нужны в аргументах, они используются только внутри самой функции, а в аргументе указывайте только сам исходный массив